# cd ./... error : "No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, terminal

I can't manage to get that instruction right : "Open Terminal. Type cd . Include the space! Now drag your mod's folder into Terminal and press Enter."
Because every time I do it displays that error.

Thanks in advance if you know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I happen to have [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) installed, but what's `dc` in your case? Should be `cd` no?

Comment: Also, `cd ...` will complain of no such path. It's only Windoze that interprets up 2 levels with that command.

Comment: Yea it's cd. I corrected that sorry, and I didn't get your explanation here

Comment: What instructions, are you sure they are for Mac (Unix)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes I'm sure, although I don't know if the author is actually talking about a specific OS version. If you want to take a look at it here's the link. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mods/Creating_mods/Setting_up_the_MCP_workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the dot (.), it looks like a typo and just type `cd` followed by a space and then drag the folder into the terminal window and then press enter to be moved to the correct folder

Comment: I've done it and it now says: 'MacBook-Pro-de-Miguel-2:MinerMod miloertas$' at line beginning which seems correct, However, when I then type `bash updatemcp.sh` it gives me ''env: python2: No such file or directory" so if you know what I've done wrong again I'd be more than happy, Otherwise I'll just post another question... Ty anyways

Comment: Looks like python2 is not in your path. You could edit the .sh file and change python2 to python, that should work.